# Order of usage: Raging Strikes and DoTs

Tags: final-fantasy-14

My understanding of Raging Strikes is unclear.

> Increases damage dealt by 20%.

Seems simple enough, right? XD

What I want to know is how this 20% boost interacts with my SMN damage-over-time attacks. Does the 20% apply to the individual ticks of damaging, or does it apply to the DoT debuff as a whole?

If the former, then RS should be used after applying my DoTs to maximise the effects. If the latter, then it should be used first so that it applies to the DoTs.

I think it's the former, boosting the damage inflicted each tick. This would make the most sense to me, but I've seen sources on various forums showing RS before applying DoTs in their rotations.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DoTs use a snapshot of all your buffs at the time of casting, so if you use RS first, then cast the DoTs, they will be boosted for their entire duration.

I can't find a dev post about it, but there is discussion [here](http://forum.square-enix.com/ffxiv/threads/123824-SMNS-and-Mega-INT-Pots), and in many other places.

Comment: So if I continue renewing the DOTs without letting them expire, do they continue to have RS's effect, or does re-applying them without RS make it recalculate the damage done? How does Contagion affect this, if at all?

Comment: reapplying when you dont have RS, makes them lose their buff.

Comment: Would I be correct in thinking that since Contagion doesn't re-apply buffs, it simply extends them... I can extend RS-boosted DOTs even if the RS itself has ended?

Answer (score 2):

It makes individual ticks stronger, you want to use all your buffs first, then all your DoTs.

By the way the buff effect is per skill use:
you use raging strikes, all skills used during raging strikes will get the buff (for the entire duration of the DoT).

if you use a DoT while raging strikes has 1 sec to end, then that DoT will have all the bonus damage from raging strikes for ALL the DoT duration.